# copilotos que fizeram o maior número de voos

Tags: sql

Tenho este esta pergunta:

Nome e n.º de horas de voo dos copilotos que fizeram o maior número de voos.
Pretende-se saber o n.º exato de voos feitos por cada um desses copilotos

E tentei resolver assim :

```
SELECT t.nome , p1.n_horas_voo , COUNT( * ) as n_de_voos
FROM   Tripulante t , Piloto p1 , Voo v
WHERE  t.id = v.id_copiloto
   AND v.id_copiloto = p1.id
        GROUP BY ( t.apelido )
        HAVING COUNT( * ) >= ALL( SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Voo v2)
```

No entanto o meu output é este

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e deveria ser apenas o Carlos pois é o copiloto que fez mais voos. O que estou a fazer mal? Ou como resolvo esta pergunta?

Tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o banco de dados?

Comment: Pelo que eu vi sairam duas respostas na pergunta que resolveriam o problema ou ao menos encaminhariam para uma solução. Lá você disse que nao pode usar subquery, sem explicar o motivo. Também já tem outras perguntas parecidas com a sua no site, com o mesmo problema de falta de clareza. Acho que é o caso de você ler o [Tour] e [Ask], e [edit] a pergunta elaborando melhor e explicando todas as condições necessárias de antemão, pois pelos seus comments, entendo que a pergunta Não Está Clara o suficiente para que as pessoas respondam o que você espera.

Comment: Elaborando melhor, todos saem ganhando, pois aumenta a chance de sair alguma resposta que resolva o seu problema, e evita que pessoas percam tempo respondendo algo que não vai servir por motivos que não foram colocados na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Se for SLQServer fica assim:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.nome , p1.n_horas_voo , COUNT( * ) as n_de_voos
FROM   Tripulante t , Piloto p1 , Voo v
WHERE  t.id = v.id_copiloto
   AND v.id_copiloto = p1.id
        GROUP BY ( t.apelido )
        HAVING COUNT( * ) >= ALL( SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Voo v2)
```

MySQL acho que usa limit:

```
    SELECT t.nome , p1.n_horas_voo , COUNT( * ) as n_de_voos
        FROM   Tripulante t , Piloto p1 , Voo v
        WHERE  t.id = v.id_copiloto
           AND v.id_copiloto = p1.id
                GROUP BY ( t.apelido )
                HAVING COUNT( * ) >= ALL( SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM Voo v2)
        Limit 1
```

Só confere se não é melhor você usar um Order By

Comment: Nao posso usar nem o TOP nem o Limit, tenho de formular a querry de forma a que me retorne apenas um registo sem que tenha de fazer uma restrição.

Answer (score 1):

Para saber total de voos (ciclos):

```
SELECT TMP.* 
  FROM (SELECT T.Id, T.Nome, Count(*) Voos
          FROM Tripulante T
          JOIN Voo V ON V.Id_CoPiloto = T.Id
         GROUP BY T.Id, T.Nome) TMP
 ORDER BY TMP.Voos DESC
```

Para saber total de horas:

```
SELECT TMP.* 
  FROM (SELECT T.Id, T.Nome, Sum(V.Data_Chegada - V.Data_Partita) Horas
          FROM Tripulante T
          JOIN Voo V ON V.Id_CoPiloto = T.Id
         GROUP BY T.Id, T.Nome) TMP
 ORDER BY TMP.Horas DESC
```

Não testei, mas deve ser de bom adianto.

Comment: Nao posso usar from com select's ou com condiçoes la dentro infelizmente

Comment: @Esteves, por curiosidade, pq não pode?

Comment: @Esteves, vc pode executar sem a subquery, daí vc ordena o resultado no lado da aplicação. Sem erro. :)

Comment: Nao me é permitido utilizar,
De qualquer das maneiras eu quero como output o nome e numero de horas de voo do piloto que fez o maior numero de voos por isso, so preciso contar o numero de voos .

Comment: Entendo, bom, como eu disse, não precisa, executa apenas a subquery, e o resultado vc orderna no php. Atende, @Esteves?